# Is there a Jade Library for Haskell?

Tags: haskell, pug

I have a server for my site written in go that uses [Amber](https://github.com/eknkc/amber) templates (Amber is go's version of Jade, which is from PHP). Since the site is full of files of that format, I want to create a Haskell server that will serve them just like the go server does. Trying to see if one is better than the other.

I have looked everywhere for a jade package written in Haskell. I have seen questions from people saying they are developing one, but I can not find a finished product. Does anyone know of one? Or, does anyone have an idea how to add something like this to Haskell?

Comment: Have you tried asking on the haskell reddit or the IRC channel?

Comment: No. I have never used Reddit or IRC. I mostly come here for answers without having to go through a lot of junk.

Comment: You could give it a try! People on the IRC channel are very friendly and welcoming. Also, I think this question is more suited for that kind of place (as you can see, this question has been put on hold as off-topic, since stack overflow doesn't like questions that are about recommending libraries).

Comment: I have it on Reddit right now. No one know anything about one.

Comment: Then I guess you can conclude it doesn't exist... You are of course welcome to write your own one and publish it. However, this is probably outside the scope of your project :P

Answer (score 0):

Did you find [shakespeare](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shakespeare) yet? Shakespeare is what the [Yesod Web Framework](http://www.yesodweb.com/) uses for HTML, CSS and Javascript creation. So i guess it must be usefull.

Comment: Shakespeare is good, but it doesn't do Jade translation. I have a server for my site written in go that uses Amber templates (Amber is go's version of Jade, which is from PHP). Since the site is full of files of that format, I want to create a Haskell server that will serve them just like the go server does. Trying to see if one is better than the other.